# Set jPicker field to empty value

Tags: jquery, jpicker

Im using jPicker as color selector in a form.
All I have to do is clear its value then set its window/icon to 'no color selected' state.

I've tried the following:

```
$(':input[name="color"]').val(''); //Access its value directly. (Does not affect jPicker)
```

2:

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('hex', '', this); //Set color to black and input value to 000000, instead of empty string
```

3:

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val(null, '', this); //Does nothing
```

None of the 3 methods seems to behave properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :)

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('v', null);
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Up7n/

Comment: thank you. I think its a difference between empty string and null at the 2nd parameter